# Why does django tutorial allow users to vote multiple times on a poll? How can I fix it?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have been following the django tutorial for building the polls application and I don't understand why would an application allow users to vote multiple times on a poll.

Comment: *Simplicity*. Identifying unique anonymous visitors (those that don't identify by logging in) is **hard**. Even with logins, people can create more.

Comment: The codes in the tutorial is just quick example how is Django organized, how to write codes and where to look up in the docs in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

### Why

Well, it is more complicated to implement what you described, and for a tutorial, you want simple code. This also requires authentication to identify the user, to get the `request.user` value that I'll use below (a value that isn't always available unless e.g. the view is set to `login_required`)

### How to fix

With the models in the tutorial, I'm afraid it's not possible to do that, because when a user votes, all that happens is a `selected_choice += 1` operation, which as you can see, does not log the user.

If you wanted to log the user in a vote, you'd have to create a model to do that, e.g.

```
class Vote(Model):
    question = ForeignKey(Question)
    selected_choice = ForeignKey(Choice)
    user = ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('question', 'user'),
        )
```

Having a `unique_together` like the above makes sure our database can only one choice vote *per user per question*

Here's some pseudo code on how to handle a vote action

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    user = request.user
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])

    # Update the vote info, or create if doesn't exist yet 
    Vote.objects.update_or_create(
        user=user,
        question=question,
        defaults={'selected_choice': selected_choice}
    )

    # Recalculate the select choice counts for the question
    # For the question, set each question.choice to the count
```